# Why does my VB.Net Project disappear instead of giving an error message?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, error-handling

Why does my VB.Net Project disappear instead of giving an error message?
This only started happening recently, but when debugging with Visual Studios instead of getting errors, the program just closes as though the stop button was pressed. This doesn’t happen for all error types but it consistently happens if there is some sort of casting error. 
This is an overly simplified example, but the lines below would cause a program to vanish as soon as they run.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    i = "A"
```

One other interesting part of this is that if that was in a try catch block the error would be caught instead of closing the program. 
I’m in an office setting so I’ve been able to test a number of configurations and have found that this problem only affects Windows XP PCs, but not Windows 7. And it consistently happens with Visual Studios 2010 Professional and Ultimate, Visual Studios 2008.

Anybody have any ideas? Besides that we apparently we all need Windows 7.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you do not have `break when Common Language Runtime Exceptions Thrown` checked? (CTRL + ALT + E)

Comment: Thrown is unchecked, but User-Unhandled is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Cant expect error of casting first of all he have to underline your error. Then you have to correct it before debugging.

Your VS shows you the red underline in errors or not ??

And if the VS shows you that errors exist when you debug ?

Comment: The Error is not underlined or otherwise marked before running the code.
With further testing I also found out that this only happens with .Net 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5, but 4.0 behaves normally.

Comment: You're forgetting those miserable days before you turned option dufus off (oops, I meant before you turned option strict on).  With option dufus on, you can have as many casting errors in the compiled assembly as you can shake a stick at.

Comment: Nice try Steve Dog but Strict is turned off. More over that would just cause more errors, it wouldn't cause programs to end instead of giving errors